# Loop in RPG for addition of repeated values

Tags: ibm-midrange, jdedwards

Can someone tell me how to add the values of a repeated item in RPG,consider I have the same employee record repeatedly in File with his allowance data,i want to sum up his allowance,then what should I do in RPG?

Comment: It depends... Will you use native I/O or SQL? You should know that this really isn't quite a "tutorial" site.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the site :P,am talking about RPG here not SQl

Comment: Let's try to get this on topic. Edit the question with answers to: What have you tried? What happened? What languages do you know?

Answer (score 0):

if the file you are reading is Keyed by employee # or some such, you can load a "key".  RPG400 looks like ....

Move *OFF  *IN30

key  SETLL Filename

*IN30  DOWEQ   *OFF

KEY   READE  Filename     *IN30

*IN30   *IFEQ   *ON

```
      LEAVE

      ENDIF
```

"add your tot to a running accum"

```
   ENDDO
```